# Error setting color for Text in TextView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, text, colors, formatting

I am trying to set the Text Color of a TextView in Android Studio and in the preview in Android Studio it appears fine... However, When running it on a physical device, it shows a completely different color.

This is the TextView in the XML file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="268dp"
    android:text="Book S Mart is a place where \npeople can exchange used and new\nbooks of all types.\n\nEvery year millions of books\nare sent to recycling although they can be used again\n\nOur goal is to provide these books to those in need as well as Help the environment"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/homeText"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and this is the `colors.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#6200EE</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#3700B3</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#03DAC5</color>
    <color name="homeText">#060E5A</color>
</resources>
```

Here's how it appears in Android Studio:
[image: On Android Studio]

and here's how it appears on my device (Using USB debugging)

[image: On My Mobile Phone Redmi K20 Pro]

How do I set the Color properly?

Comment: very weird behavior... maybe try to Build -> Clean project in Android Studio, then install debug version

Comment: can you confirm that the JAVA file doesnt have any code related to Textcolor?

Comment: No Code in Java File related to TextColor...

Comment: try this on different physical devices and see

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Try a different color without using colors.xml. (Example: `android:textColor="#000000"`)
2. Try it on an emulator.
3. Go to `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`. It will clear caches and restart Android Studio.
4. Go to `Build > Clean Project`, then `Build > Rebuild Project`.

You can try these solutions.

Comment: I ran it on an emulator and it works perfectly but how do I make sure this error does not occur on any other device after I bundle it and share it as an APK?

Comment: Is this problem occurs in all colors or just this color?

Comment: I've tries various shades of blue and black... The problem occurs in all of them

Comment: It can be an Android version issue. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm compiling for 22 and above but running it on 30

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon device, Try with another device or emulator. This is not color code issue.